# Fullcalendar edit

Tags: fullcalendar, filemaker

there is a completed project with a calendar for the whole year with drag and drop.[FullCalendar](http://plnkr.co/edit/1I9qfzuHSsoZnQq4lzz5?p=preview)
Where it is necessary to change and on what [that month looked here](http://joxi.ru/1A5K6kEFnjOQXm) and filling of action occurred [so](http://joxi.ru/p27adypUozjp6r), but[not so](http://joxi.ru/LmG9NoOIe05KpA)
I will be glad of any help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/ru.js"></script>
  <script src="fullcalendar.js"></script>
   
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for this setting: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/showNonCurrentDates . But I'm not sure - your question is very unclear. I think perhaps in future you should ask someone to translate for you, if you are struggling to write clearly in English.

Comment: Fine, but in this case, she only hides the days in the first and last month, and Yes, forgive my English.)

Comment: you mean that's what you want it to do, or that's what the code is doing when you try to use it? If there's a problem, please link me to a demo which shows the issue. Thanks.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1I9qfzuHSsoZnQq4lzz5?p=preview

Comment: Here you can see how now it works, that's the question that needs to be changed under my requirements?

Comment: How is this related to FileMaker?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that Plunker that you used showNonCurrentDates. I can't understand your problem if you don't show me the code that is causing you a difficulty.

Comment: P.S. It seems you have got some customised version of fullCalendar with a "year" view in it, and I don't know what version of the base fullCalendar it's derived from? The showNonCurrentDates option will (as you see in the documentation) only work on version 3.3.0 and above. And that option normally only applies to "month" views...I don't know if your "year" view will use it or not (and no I'm not going to read the whole source code to find out, sorry).